# Tensor product distributes over coproducts

Tags: homological-algebra, tensor-products

I am trying to prove some properties of the tensor product. So firstly I want to show that the tensor product distributes over finite direct sums, i.e. $M \otimes_R (P \oplus Q) \cong (M \otimes_R P) \oplus (M \otimes_R Q)$

**My attempt:**

Let

$\Lambda: M \times (P \oplus Q) \rightarrow (M \otimes_R P) \oplus (M \otimes_R Q)$ by $\Lambda(m, (p + q)) = (m \otimes \pi_P(p + q)) + (m \otimes \pi_Q(p + q)) = (m \otimes p) + (m \otimes q)$.

Here $p \in P$ and $q \in Q$ and $\pi_P$ and $\pi_Q$ are the projections from the biproduct onto $P$ and $Q$ respectively.

One can easily show that $\Lambda$ is $R-$balanced, due to the fact that its image is contained in a tensor product. Hence by the universal property of the tensor product $\exists!  \bar{\Lambda}: M \otimes_R (P \oplus Q) \rightarrow (M \otimes_R P) \oplus (M \otimes_R Q)$. $\bar{\Lambda}$ takes $(m \otimes (p + q))$ to $(m \otimes p) + (m \otimes q)$.

Define $\Theta:(M \otimes_R P) \oplus (M \otimes_R Q) \rightarrow M \otimes_R (P \oplus Q)$ by $\Theta((m \otimes p) + (m \otimes q)) = m \otimes (\iota_P(p) + \iota_Q(q))$

Here $\iota_P$ and $\iota_Q$ are the inclusions of $P$ and $Q$ into the biproduct.

We see that $\Theta(\bar{\Lambda}(m \otimes (p + q))) = m \otimes (p + q)$ and $\bar{\Lambda}(\Theta((m \otimes p) + (m \otimes q))) = (m \otimes p) + (m \otimes q)$

Making $\bar{\Lambda}$ and isomorphism.

**Q1)** Is this correct?

**Q2)** Can my attempted proof be extended to infinite coproducts, that is $M \otimes_R \coprod_{i \in I} P_i \cong  \coprod_{i \in I} (M \otimes_R P_i)$.

Comment: The proof is correct and for the general argument (which is very similiar) see the above link. Note: The infinite coproduct of $R$-modules is the infinite direct sum and usually denoted by $\bigoplus_i P_i$ rather than $\coprod_i P_i$.

Comment: @mrtaurho Ok, thanks! I was wondering; does the infinite coproduct and infinite product coincide as well? Is there a notion of an infinite biproduct?

Comment: No, the infinite coproduct (the direct sum) is in general different from the infinite product (the direct product): if you take just the base ring as factor one is free, the other not. For this reason I could imagine requiring both universal properties, i.e. defininig a biproduct, would force triviality.